# Show child component only after data is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In my parent component I have:

```
<v-container fluid>
  <ResultsPanel ref="results" />
</v-container>
```

ResultsPanels is:

```
<template v-if="showResults">
   <v-container > IM SHOWIN!</v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: "ResultsPanel",
   data: () => ({
       fiData: [],
       analysisData: [],
   }),
   computed: {
       showResults() {
           return (this.analysisData && this.analysisData.length > 0)
       }
   }
 }
 </script>
```

I want to use:

```
this.$ref.resultsTable.analysisData = [some, returned, data,]
```

in the parent component after an axios call returns to cause the ResultsPanel to show. Before this is set, when analysisData is [], it want the whole ResultsPanel component to be hidden. How can I accomplish this?

Currently, the component shows regardless of whether or not data is present. If I move the v-if to the v-container, it never shows even after data is added to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use props like this:

parent component:

```
<v-container fluid>
  <ResultsPanel ref="results" :analysisData="analysisData" v-if="showResults"/>
</v-container>
...
data: () => ({
       analysisData: []
   }),
 computed: {
     showResults() {
         return (this.analysisData && this.analysisData.length > 0)
     }
 }
...
methods: {
  setData () {
    this.analysisData = [some, returned, data,] 
  }
}
```

child component:

````
<template>
   <v-container > IM SHOWIN!</v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: "ResultsPanel",
   props: {
        analysisData: {
           type: Array,
           default: () => []
        },
   data: () => ({
       fiData: [],
   })
 }
 </script>```
````

Comment: My question was slightly misleading in that I was actually waiting for an object to return from the server, not an array. To compensate for that, I added a boolean to my data object that I update to true when the server returns data. Is there a better way to do this? Your suggestion does work though besides that.

Comment: `data: () => ({
       analysisData: null
   }),`

`showResults() {
         return (this.analysisData)
     }`

`
props: {
        analysisData: {
           type: Object,
           default: () => null
        }
`